# Processing text array in PostgresSQL and convert to integer array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a column in Postgres of type text array -
example - `{"Jun:2022,000/STD","May:2022,320/STD","Apr:2022,100/STD","Mar:2022,720/DDD","Feb:2022,000/STD"}`

I want to convert it into integer array by keeping only last 3 digit before "/" symbol

output - `{000,320,100,720,000}`

Comment: Is it postgres or mysql?

Comment: `select array_agg(substr(item, 10, 3)::int) from table cross join lateral unnest(column) as un(item);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing your string format is consistent as in your examples, then the solution by @MikeOrganek is a good one. However if the format varies then a regular expression is called for. Perhaps something like:

```
with test( val ) as 
     ( select array['Jun:2022 xxx,000/STD','May:2022,320/STD','Apr:2022,100/STD','Mar:2022,720/DDD','Feb:2022,000/STD'] )
-- your query begins here
select array_agg(regexp_replace( item, '.*(\d{3})\/', '\1')::integer) "Integer Array"
  from  (select unnest(val) item from test) s
```